# R connecting with SQL Server

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, t-sql, rstudio

I have developed this code in SQL

```
*enter code here*


SELECT *
FROM database1
WHERE (Name LIKE '%T%') AND (City NOT LIKE '%Tokyo')
```

The above code in SQL gives in the answer I want in SSMS

But I am using R studio where I am getting a user response in a textbox named "input$txtbx" and building the SQL statement along the same lines as the above.

```
enter code here

dbcontext("SELECT * FROM database1 WHERE Name LIKE", '%input$txtbx%',";")
```

where in **'%input$txtbx%'** I want to get the value that user puts and matches with the LIKE operator in the SQL statement mentioned above for db context.

So for an example, if user inputs letter 'z' then it should be something like this.

```
enter code here

dbcontext("SELECT * FROM database1 WHERE Name LIKE", '%z%',";")
```

Both the code (in SSMS as well as in R Studio should yield same results) but I am getting an error saying **Incorrect Syntax near 'input$txtbx'.**

can somebody help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

```
dbcontext(paste0("SELECT * FROM database1 WHERE Name LIKE", " '%",input$txtbx,"%'",";"))

# try again with con being the connection to the database:
 dbGetQuery(con, paste0("SELECT * FROM database1 WHERE Name LIKE", " '%",input$txtbx,"%'",";"))
```

Comment: With the above query     dbcontext(paste0("SELECT * FROM database1 WHERE Name LIKE", " '%",input$txtbx,"%'",";"))  the results are not yield because there is a whitespace in between first % and t as soon as I run the R code   "SELECT * FROM database1 WHERE Name LIKE '%  t %' ;"    Any idea how to remove that whitespace?

Comment: try again with:

Comment: and if I want to add one more clause in WHERE statement, is this correct?                 paste0("SELECT * FROM database1 WHERE income = ", input$txtbx12, " AND name LIKE", " '%",input$txtbx,"%'",";")

Comment: If you are using the DBI package dbGetQuery(connection variable, “ANY VALID SQL QUERY”) will work.